# How do I determine whether calculation was completed, or detect interrupted calculation?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large workbook that takes a really long time to calculate. It used to be quite a challenge to get it to calculate all the way, since Excel is so eager to silently abort calculation if you so much as look at it.

To help alleviate the problem, I created some VBA code to initiate the the calculation, which is initiated by a form, and the result is that it is not quite as easy to interrupt the calculation process, but it is still possible. (I can easily do this by clicking the close X on the form, but I imagine there are other ways)

Rather than taking more steps to try and make it harder to interrupt calculation, I'd like to have the code detect whether calculation is complete, so it can notify the user rather than just blindly forging on into the rest of the steps in my code. So far, I can't find any way to do that.

I've seen references to Application.CalculationState, but the value is xlDone after I interrupt calculation, even if I interrupt the calculation after a few seconds (it normally takes around an hour).

I can't think of a way to do this by checking the value of cells, since I don't know which one is calculated last. I see that there is a way to mark cells as "dirty" but I haven't been able to find a way to check the dirtiness of a cell. And I don't know if that's even the right path to take, since I'd likely have to check every cell in every sheet.

The act of interrupting calculation does not raise an error, so my ON ERROR doesn't get triggered.

Is there anything I'm missing? Any ideas?

Any ideas?

Comment: You can prevent the interruption from occurring, but I would suggest that you spend some effort speeding up the calculation: an hour to calculate is extremely excessive. See http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeed.htm or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700515.aspx

Comment: I heartily agree. But even if I reduce the script run time by an order of magnitude, it's going to be running for 6 minutes, and I'll still wonder, given Excel's tendency to be so quiet about interrupted calculation, whether my data is accurate.

I'm actually less interested in preventing the interruption and more interested in knowing whether an interruption occurred.

Comment: Great question. I notice that when calculation is interrupted, the word "Calculate" appears in the status bar. Other than simply looking at the status bar, I don't know of any way to leverage that information.

Comment: Application.Calculationstate corresponds to the StatusBar Ready/Calculate/Calculating message. Since Ben says this is xlDone when interrupted I suspect he may be using VBA to iteratively drive calculation. Hard to say without looking at the code ...

Comment: I would recommend breaking the workbook into mulitple workbooks (preferable generating a new file each time). This will say with confidence that the calculation is complete

Comment: >>since Excel is so eager to silently abort calculation if you so much as look at it<< With experience in every version of Excel, this statement is nonsense.

Comment: My most complex workbook at 128MB took 20 minutes to manually calculate and generate the data for one report. (There where four reports total.) I redesigned the workbook to use pivot tables as calculators, reworked the formulas, added precalculated values, used arrays for calculations, and so on. The result was reports taking 2 to 5 minutes. In Excel 2007, the results are 1 to 3 minutes. One hour is not a solution.

Comment: I don't know at what exact Excel calculation duration time it's appropriate to stop and say, "Hang on, this is taking far too long, let's rethink how this is done", but I'm fairly sure it's well before **an hour** ...

Comment: The reason it takes an hour is because of a vast number of highly complex array formulas, not because of large amounts of data. I agree that it's a totally inappropriate solution, and it's because Excel is not an appropriate tool for what we're doing. We have time scheduled to completely rewrite the system in an actual programming language within the next year or two. However, that does not help me ensure that our data is correct in the meantime. My question would still stand if it only took a minute to calculate.

Comment: You could read the old output value, store it in a named range via VBA, write a formula similar to if(A1<>oldResult,"Done","") to a cell where A1 is the result.  If calculation is interrupted since this depends on the result it wouldn't have calculated and wouldn't show "Done".

Comment: An interesting idea. It would work great if I was working toward a single result value, or even just a few. Unfortunately, there are hundreds of result values in across several worksheets.
Also, it's not inconceivable that a result value would coincidentally be the same after processing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the trick you need to implement (if you're application runs in Excel 2007 or later) is to handle this with the Application.AfterCalculate event, which is raised after both calculation is complete *and* there are no outstanding queries.

If you've never worked with events in VBA before, there is a good overview from [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

On the status bar, right hand side, it will say `Calculating (N processors) X%` (where `N` is the number of processors on your computer and `X%` is how much it has completed) when recalculating.  If you don't see text there, it's not recalculating.

I'm using Office 2010, but it should be there in all versions.  It's just kinda subtle so it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

The (MSDN) solution by Charles Williams above worked for me where I had 1000's of VLOOKUP's that neeeded to recalculate as the code was changing the lookup value because of an iteration loop. Results were skewed as calculations were not running to 100% completion.

At the beginning of my subroutine the code executes

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

This eliminated unnecessary calculations by Excel until I was ready.

Now at the critical point the code executes

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
ThisWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = True
Application.Calculate
```

Having forced Excel to perform a full calculation, the code could then saved the result and move onto the next iteration ... but before doing so

```
ThisWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Remembering at the very end

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually used it but I think this might work to prevent calculation from being interrupted.

`Application.CalculationInterruptKey = xlNoKey`

Comment: That can help prevent accidental interruption, but still won't let me find out whether calculation has been interrupted or not.

Comment: You are right. It is more an end run around the problem. (Assuming it works.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm hearing that you need a way to monitor whether each step within the calculations being performed was executed.

Assuming that you're not interested in re-engineering the workbook to use methods that are easier to track than spreadsheet calculations (such as volatile calculations within VBA or Pivot Tables), this may work for you:

Within VB, you can utilize **.EnableCalculation** and **.Calculate** to set an entire worksheet as "Dirty" (needing calculation) and then recalculate. The key difference between this and your current process is that we will perform these actions *one worksheet at a time* in manual mode. By initiating the calculations one worksheet at a time from within VBA, you will be able to perform additional intermediate actions that can be used to track how far you got in the calculation process.

Please note that this approach assumes a fairly linear workbook structure such that your workbook will produce the correct results if we first recalculate Sheet1, then Sheet2, Sheet3, and so on, in whatever order you wish. If your formula dependencies are more "spaghetti" than linear, this probably won't work for you. It also assumes you are working in Excel 2000 or later.

For example, you could write a VBA routine that accomplishes the following steps.
You will need to know your dependencies in order to know which calculations must come before others, and start with the worksheet in a "clean" state where no calculations are currently pending.

**Step 1**: Set the active sheet to the first worksheet where recalculation is needed

**Step 2**: Set the calculation mode to manual as follows:

```
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

**Step 3**: "Dirty" the entire active sheet as follows:

```
    With ActiveSheet

    .EnableCalculation = False

    .EnableCalculation = True
```

**Step 4**: Initiate a recalculation for this worksheet only (not the entire workbook) using:

```
    .Calculate

    End With
```

Note that if the calculation mode were set to automatic, Step 3 would initiate a re-calculation across the entire workbook. By using manual mode and With, we are constraining that calculation to the current sheet.

Now you have dirtied and re-calculated the first sheet (hurray!). Now, by embedding Steps 3 and 4 above into a For/Each or For/Next loop, you can repeat the process for each worksheet in your workbook. Again, make sure you know the order in which your worksheets need to be calculated (if an order is needed).

Now for the big finish - by creating a counter variable within your loop, you can track how far you got in the calculations by updating your counter variable value each time you complete a worksheet calculation. For example, after you recalculate a worksheet, you can set the counter value to current value + 1 and store the results either in a global variable (so that it will persist even after your VBA routine ends), or in a cell within your worksheet. That way, you can check this value later to see how many worksheets were updated before the calculations finished or were interrupted.

If you have relatively few worksheets in your workbooks, the same approach could be applied to one range at a time rather than a sheet.

I won't go into detail about how to construct a "counter", loops, or global variables here, but if needed, this information can be easily found using your favorite search engine. I would also highly recommend re-enabling automatic calculations once you are done as it is easy to forget that it's been set to manual mode.

I hope this works for you - for more information on calculation modes and recalculation, this is a helpful link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my experience so far has been that if calculation is interrupted, any code being run immediately moves on from the .calculate call, exactly as if it had completed normally. So the result of the counter wouldn't be any different whether calculation was interrupted or not.  I do still need to investigate the event-driven approach mentioned in another answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following would work:

```
Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Can't say I've tested it, nor that I know how robust the functionality of Application.CalculationState really is to determine whether 'complete' calculation occurred, as opposed to something interrupting the process and flagging the calculation state as done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private sub SomeCodeThatGeneratesFormulas
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
    '...Some formulas are copied here'
    Application.OnTime DateTime.DateAdd ("s",.01,DateTime.Now), "Module1.CalculateFullRebuildAndSubsequentSteps" 'By using Application.OnTime, this method will be called in a way that locks the end-user out of providing inputs into Excel until the calculation itself is complete.
end sub

public sub CalculateFullRebuildAndSubsequentSteps
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    '...Do next steps, i.e. paste as values'
end sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays in Excel can be a bit stupid. That is that in order to accomplish some tasks people avoid to use intermediate columns/rows to store (temporary) data, so arrays have to recalculate staff from the beginning every time, thus getting really slow. My Suggestion would be:

1. fix arrays to avoid multiple searches. Use hidden cells or even hidden sheets
2. Avoid using A:A and rather use A1:A1000 specially in excel 2007 or later
3. use formulas to equal zero or error (ex: NA()) while previous items aren't calculated, so you can clearly see if an operation is done at all.
4. some VBA could be used to inject formulas in place one step at a time, perform calculations, then proceed to next step, but this could mean lots of work...